CSRF CSRF utility package invalid CSRF Token Error
Because CSURF has been deprecated I have been trying to use doule CSRF utility package but am finding some of their docs confusing. In my express typescript backend I have set up csrf csrf like this but am getting a forbidden 403 invalid csrf token error whenever my frontend makes requests.
Backend code snippet:
App.ts snippet:
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(middleware.requestLogger);
app.use(middleware.limiter);
app.use(middleware.authenticateApiKey);
app.use('/', csrfRouter);
app.use(middleware.doubleCsrfProtection);"

middleware.ts snippet:
"const { generateToken, doubleCsrfProtection } = doubleCsrf({
    getSecret: () => {
        if (config.CSRF_SECRET === undefined) {
            throw new Error('CSRF_SECRET is not defined in the configuration');
        }
        return config.CSRF_SECRET;
    },
    cookieName: '__x-csrf-movies',
    cookieOptions: {
        secure: true,
    },
});

export default {
    generateToken,
    doubleCsrfProtection
};

csrfRouter.ts:
import express from 'express';
import middleware from '../utils/middleware';

const csrfRouter = express.Router();

csrfRouter.get('/csrf', (request, response) => {
    const csrfToken = middleware.generateToken(request, response);
    // You could also pass the token into the context of a HTML response.
    response.json({ csrfToken });
});

export default csrfRouter;

Frontend code snippet:
// Fetch CSRF token from backend
const fetchCsrfToken = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(${config.BACKEND_URL}/csrf, {
            headers: {
                'x-api-key': config.API_KEY,
            },
        })
        return response.data.csrfToken
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch CSRF token:', error)
        throw new Error('CSRF token fetch failed')
    }
}

const loginService = async (credentials: { username: string, password: string }): Promise<LoginType> => {
    const csrfToken = await fetchCsrfToken()

    const request = axios.post<LoginType>(${config.BACKEND_URL}/login, credentials, {
        headers: {
            'x-api-key': config.API_KEY,
            'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken,
        },
    })
    return request.then(response => {
        console.log('Login successful! Received token')
        return response.data
    })
}

Greatly appreciate any help!
